# Where to put code that generates select options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select dropdown where I generate the options from database entries, then add an option to the beginning like:

```
@select = Service.find_services_by_id(id).collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] }
@select.unshift( [ "Choose a service", 0] )
```

Then in the HAML view I have:

```
=select_tag "service_id", options_for_select(@select)
```

But I'm looking at refactoring that either by:

1) Adding another method to the model which also does the unshift operation to return to me all the data for the select in one piece

2) Moving the whole @select definition to a view helper and calling it from the view

3) Just have that first @select line in the controller, then have a view helper do the 'unshift' part

But I'm having trouble figuring out what makes the most sense. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for 3rd, but not only do the `unshift` in the helper, but create whole `select` thingie there too:

```
module SomeHelper
  def service_select(objects)
    select_tag "service_id", options_for_select(objects.unshift(["Select a service", 0]))
  end
end
```

Then in view you'd just call `=service_select(@select)`.

Comment: That sounds a lot like the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

1) does not make a lot of sense. The model should not be sticking headers on data to pretty it up - that's the view's job.

2) and 3) are both reasonable - I'm personally leaning towards 3), but either one is good.